# Is Spider-Man working for the United Nations due to the Sokovia Accords?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

The Sokovia Accords state that the Avengers, and other super-powered individuals, are under the control of the United Nations. Since Spider-Man was on Tony's side in the conflict and is not a fugitive by the end, does that mean that Spider-Man is also under the control of the United Nations?

Also, since one of the stipulations was that superheroes can't act without the approval of the United Nations, does that mean that he has to contact them whenever he wants to do something?

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if there are provisions for under age super heroes. Peter Parker is a high school kid at this point, right?

Comment: I think the only reason Spider-man is not a fugitive at the end of the film is because Tony didn't want him to be. If he wanted the UN to have control over Spider-man, why'd he give him a suit with a mask?

Comment: The principles of the Sokovia accords were that all "supers" had to register with the UN. It was only the Avengers that were specifically called out to work under the oversight of the UN panel. I assume this same panel would also have the right to simply demand a super stop their activities or demand they work alongside local forces (police, etc).

Comment: I suspect we're not going to have a definitive answer on this until _Spider-man: Homecoming_ premieres.

Comment: @Valorum: “The principles of the Sokovia accords were that all "supers" had to register with the UN.” Did they? Was that stated somewhere in the film? (Or separately?)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - There's a reference in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. to the President suspecting that Coulson has been using "unregistered" inhumans as part of his strike teams.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a sort-of counterpoint to @KutuluMike’s answer, I’m going to say: in practice, no he’s not.

In *Civil War*, we only see Tony Stark make contact with Peter Parker, and he only does it to get Spider-Man’s help with his attempt to capture Captain America and Bucky Barnes.

This capture attempt seems to operate outside of the Sovokia Accords: Tony specifically asks Secretary Ross for 72 hours to bring in Cap (and gets 36 hours), instead of getting a decision from the United Nations panel.

Stark is quite protective of Spider-Man during this operation: he specifically tells him to hang back and use his webbing to restrain opponents, and is visibly scared when he sees Spider-Man injured at the end of the fight. Importantly I think, he also uses the threat of telling Peter’s Aunt May about his superpowers to make Peter do what he wants.

As such, I think it’s unlikely that Tony revealed Spider-Man’s identity (or possibly even existence) to the United Nations. Surely if he had revealed it, that would have quickly resulted in Aunt May knowing about it too, and would risk high-school kid Peter suffering the kind of imprisonment that Scarlet Witch and friends went through, which Tony seems at least ambivalent about by the end of the movie.

So: I think the UN remains mostly unaware of Spider-Man’s activities, and almost certainly unaware of his secret identity. As such, I don’t think Spider-Man is working for them.

Comment: the title of the question says "working for", but the body of the question says "under the control of ". He's most likely not working for the UN but he *definitely* falls under their control, and using his powers without their permission almost certainly violates the Accords. His secret identity should be irrelevant.

Comment: @KutuluMike: “he *definitely* falls under their control” — he is presumably within the purview of the Accords, yes (obviously none of us has read them, so we can’t be sure of the precise definitions therein). I just mean the UN isn’t exerting any practical control or influence over Spider-Man as far as we see, and couldn’t even if they wanted to without further work, because as far as we see, they don’t even know who he is.

Answer (score 13):

It's not clear how the Accords will work, in practice, for anyone other than the current Avengers roster, but most likely yes, Peter falls under their jurisdiction.

The title page of the document says "The Sokovia Accords - Framework for the Registration and Deployment of Enhanced Individuals". This would imply that it does include anyone with naturally or artificially enhanced abilities, including Peter, who lives in any of the UN member states. (It's not clear what happens to people who live in countries that didn't sign the Accords, but that's a different question.)

The basic idea is that these people would have one of two options:

- Sign on to the accords, and put themselves under UN jurisdiction, or
- Refuse to sign on, and never use their enhanced powers again.

So yes, in theory, if Peter uses his Spider-Man abilities without UN approval, he could be considered in violation of the accords.

Note, however, that the accords were primarily directed at the Avengers *large scale, global* activities—in Sokovia, in Nigeria, in South Africa, etc. Most likely, in practice, the UN isn't going to bother with street-level vigilantes like Spider-Man or Daredevil, unless their activities grow to the point where they have a national or international impact.